# request.getParameter in jsp returns null or empty string

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets

I made an html textbox for an input and want to connect this to database.
But everytime I make an input to the textbox and move on to the result page, the result only shows the name of the attribute but not any tuples.
I think the `request.getParameter()` returns null or empty string. I did several tries but cannot find any solution.

Here's my code.
This's selectTestForm.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select the game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Input opponent team</p>
    <form name="form1" method="get" action="result.jsp">
        <p>Opponent team : <input type="text" name="oppon"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="send"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this's the result.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Find the game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="500" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Game ID</td>
            <td width="100">Opponent Team</td>
            <td width="100">Start Date</td>
        </tr>
<%
    String opponent = (String) request.getParameter("oppon");

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Driver loading error");
    }
    try{
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        String userId = "sports_booking";
        String userPass = "jade";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, userId, userPass);

        String sql = "select * from game where opponent=?";

        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, "opponent");
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while( rs.next() ) {
            String game_id = rs.getString("game_id");
            String start_date = rs.getString("start_date");

%>
            <tr>
                <td width="100"><%= game_id %></td>
                <td width="100"><%= opponent %></td>
                <td width="100"><%= start_date %></td>
            </tr>

<%
        }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

        if(rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            }catch(SQLException sqle) {} 
        }
        if(pstmt != null) {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            }catch(SQLException sqle) {}
        }
        if(con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            }catch(SQLException sqle) {}
        }
    }
%>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate if you help my problem thanks!

Comment: Hi, I would suggest at first to try oppening the result page with parameter something like this 

result.jsp?oppon=test

Comment: Try
pstmt.setString(1, "'opponent'");

Comment: @Ashish nothing happens :(

Comment: @OlehYosypenko nothing happens :(

Comment: request.getParameter("oppon") still returns null?

Comment: Can you try running your sql statement directly on sqlserver to verify if it returns the result.

Comment: @Ashish nothing happens again. I guess the while loop is the problem

Comment: If nothing happens on running sql statement on sqlserver, then probably your sql is returning no results

Comment: @Ashish But it works really well on sql developer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is line `pstmt.setString(1, "opponent");`, as you set a const `"opponent"` string instead of the variable.

`pstmt.setString(1, "opponent");` -> `pstmt.setString(1, opponent);` should work now.